# console.info() not reading variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, console

I am using console.info() to send a message to the console when I run   npm start

```
   //Imports
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = 3000

...

    //Listen on port
app.listen(port, () => console.info('Listening on port ${port}'))
```

This works to listen on port 3000 but the message returned to the console is
"Listening on port ${port}"

Any help?

Comment: Because you are using a sting, not a string literal.... `info(\`Listening on port ${port}\`)`

Comment: [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) require back-ticks (`) not single quotes.

Comment: I looked back at the tutorial I was following and they had used back ticks, thanks for this one guys, I would have never caught that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the variable outside the backticks and add it with a plus sign, like this:

```
//Listen on port

app.listen(port, () => console.info('Listening on port') +  $port)
```

Comment: Thank you, this would be easier to understand